# Intersection between ray and rectangle

Tags: c++, geometry

In C++, in 2D, how can I find the point of intersection between a ray (defined by one point and a direction-vector) and a rectangle (defined by x, y, w, h)?

```
                   ________
                  |        |
                  |        |
------------------|        |
                  |________|
```

This is for a none frame based simulation, so I am not quite sure how to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Rectangle in 2D = 4 line segments.

So your question actually is: [How do I determine whether or not two lines intersect, and if they do, at what x,y point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

You calculate intersection for all line segments and than choose closes one based on `|A-Xi|`, where `A` is *vector origin*, `Xi` is intersect point and `||` represents length of vector (`sqrt(A.x*Xi.x + A.y*Xi.y)`, you don't actually need to use `sqrt()` if you just need to compare distances and don't need exact number).

Comment: The linked question is subtly different; lines are not line segments. Also, this is apparently a special case where the rectangle isn't angled w.r.t. the major axis, i.e it's not a ♢

Comment: @MSalters Maybe it's not the exact answer he needs but I think thinking of rectangle as 4 lines is definitely the way to go in 2D (as long as he don't need internal coordinates just boundary/outside intersect point) and this is great place for him to start. If you have link to better solution I'll be glad to update my answer.

Comment: @MSalters and if my dictionary is right `line = infinite line segment` (or if you want `line segment = line with boundaries`) and than the check is really easy:
`if( (((p1.x >= x.x) && (p2.x <= x.x)) || ((p1.x <= x.x) && (p2.x >= x.x))) && (((p1.y >= x.y) && (p2.y <= x.y)) || ((p1.y <= x.y) && (p2.y >= x.y)))` (I hope I got indexes right), where the `p1` and `p2` are end points of rectangle line and `x` is intersection point.

Comment: Oh, this solution will work; it's just not the most efficient.

Comment: @MSalters if you have any enhancements or your own solution I'll be glad to edit or read your answer, because I can't imagine anything faster right now. Maybe when you're using parametric line definition such as: `y = px + q` but I'm afraid it would be the same...

Answer (score 2):

Your ray is defined by `y=px+q`. Defining your box as `{R,B,L=R+w,T=B+h}`, that means the right edge is intersected at `y=pR+q`; the left edge at `y=pL+q`, the bottom at `x=(B-q)/p` and the top at `x=(T-q)/p`.

To check that these intersections are with the line segments defining your box, you'll have to check that `R <=x && x <= L` and `B <= y && y <= T` respectively.